How to write the overload of a function that takes a class as parameter?
I have a map that contains different types (string, objects, ...) of values, under different types (string, Class, ...) of key.
When the key is a class, the value is always an instance of that class.
I've tried to write a function that correctly type its return value when known, but it doesn't work when the class constructor takes parameters:
const map = new Map();

function test<T>(key: new (...args: any[]) => T): T;
function test<T>(key: unknown): T
function test(key: unknown) {
  return map.get(key);
}

// test begin here

class A {}
class B {
  constructor(public foo: string) {}
}

const aaa = test(A) //< Correctly typed as `A`
const bbb = test(B) //< Incorrectly typed as `unknown`
const ccc = test('C') //< Correctly typed as `unknown`
const ddd = test<string>('D') //< Correctly typed as `string`

So the class B doesn't seem to be recognized by the first function overloading, but what I cannot understand is that if I remove the second function overload, then b is correctly typed as B (but then calling the function with anything else than a class fails). So why isn't B recognized as a class in the previous situation ?

I found a way by using two conditional types:
type HasConstructor<T> = T extends new (...args: any[]) => unknown ? T : never;
type ConstructorInstance<T> = T extends new (...args: any[]) => infer I ? I : never;

function test<T>(key: HasConstructor<T>): ConstructorInstance<T>;
function test<T>(key: unknown): T;
function test(key: unknown) {
  return map.get(key);
}

const aaa = test(A); //< Correctly typed as `A`
const bbb = test(B); //< Correctly typed as `B`
const ccc = test("C"); //< Correctly typed as `unknown`
const ddd = test<string>("D"); // Correctly typed as `string`

